# Does the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid ever change?

Tags: windows, winapi

Does this registry value ever change during the lifecycle of the current windows installation? (regular updates/anniversary updates/major updates)

From what I have read it is created during the windows installation, from their I can not find any specific information about this key and its lifecycle neither on google or the msdn.

Comment: If its not documented (and user editable) perhaps its not wise to make any assumptions about it.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just need a value/id generated by windows on installation that never changes unless the system is reinstalled.

Comment: If its your software create & store your own guid using the absence of such a guid as an indication of a not-seen-before state?

Comment: Its a little bit more complicated then that, I also forgot to mention the id should be "pseudo" unique (change from pc to pc upon installing windows) but its not the end of the world if two pc's out their have the same id, doesn't Windows use some kind of machine identifier that we can access that doest NOT change after updates?

Comment: There is no one single unique identifier.  Windows uses multiple sources and hardware IDs in combination to uniquely identify a machine.  Why can't you just generate your own GUID, like Alex suggested?  You only have to generate it one time, the first time you need it.  And it will be unique across different machines.

Comment: Because I wanted something attached to Windows itself. It's all right thank you for your input. I will rethink my process.

Comment: *"I wanted something attached to Windows itself."* - A custom registry key will be. When the system is installed, it doesn't exist. If the system gets re-installed, it goes away, ready to be re-created by your program. Unless you have another requirement that you didn't tell us about, this is your solution.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you. This is a great perspective and exactly what I wasn't seeing when I first was thinking of things.